# multithreading and merge sort, 3 threads for sort and merging

Tags: c

this question been asked a few times but cannot find anything specific, the topic is I'm trying to perform a merge sort using 2 threads for sorting each sub list, each thread taking a half, and a third thread to merge the two lists afterwards,

but I'm having difficulty, understanding the merge sort, (first time trying to write a sort algorithm in
c)
i know i need to lets say take "apart" the merge sort and perform only each half in two separate functions, that I can pass into the thread, then perform the final merging process, but lets say I have lists

```
list1 11 22 1 6 9
list2 99 33 4 5 7
```

I know I could write a simple sort algorithm to put each in order, but the merging process is throwing me for a loop soheres what im thinking or visualizing the error, and what i am lost on, say i sort the two lists with their different thread functions

```
list1 1 6 9 11 22
list2 4 5 7 33 99
```

I keep thinking this will be the result if I go ahead and merge them at this stage

```
1 6 9 11 22 4 5 7 33 99
```

that isn't exactly in order is it?
and if I sort them in the final merger using a sort, I mean what was the point of sorting them initially? that kind of just makes the point of sorting them in the two subthreads pointess, when my goal is to use the 2 threads and 2 threads only,  then use the final thread to merge like a merge sort would sort each array
can anyone help me visualize this better, either with code, or pseudocode?, assume that in my code I already have the array split and ready to be passed into the functions in my main(void) function, with pointers named first_half, second_half, the starter array is constructed, by taking a user input and passing that into a malloc function, and filled using random limited to 0-99

Comment: Your final result is that of concatenation, not merging. Merging uses a third list to merge the items from the first two by comparing them and adding the lower value to the third list, and then comparing the left-over item with the next item in the array from which one was "removed" (used already), and repeats until only one item has not been used, which then becomes the last item in the list.

Comment: To clarify, the first pass would compare `1` from list1 and `4` from list2, and put `1` into list3 because it's lowest. It would then compare `4` from list2 with `6` from list1, and add `4` to list3. It would then compare `6` from list1 with `5` from list2, and add `5` to list3. It would repeat this process until either one list has had all items used, and then add the remaining item(s) from the other list.

Comment: I understand the rational to have a thread to sort each sub array (b and c in my example) but I don't understand the third one for the merge_sort algo, it doesn't make sense as you would have to wait for the thread to finish first in order to avoid to write to the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way merge sort is working is by comparing the sorted element of each list together, it does not concatenate one array after another, see example code below (singlethreaded):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define _DEBUG 1

void insertion_sort(int n, int a[n])
{
    int i, tmp, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > tmp) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            --j;
        }
        a[j + 1] = tmp;
    }
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    #endif
}

void merge_sort(int n, int a[n], int x, int b[x], int y, int c[y])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) // split values of a into two arrays
        b[i] = a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        c[i] = a[i+x];
    insertion_sort(x, b); // sort each of the sub arrays, you multithread this part.
    insertion_sort(y, c);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        if (b[j] < c[k]) // you add to a the smallest between b and c.
            a[i++] = b[j++];
        else
            a[i++] = c[k++];
        if (x == j) { // if all the elements of b have filled a:
            do {
                a[i++] = c[k++]; // we proceed to fill a with c
            } while (y != k);
            break ; // the merge sorting is completed.
        }
        else if (y == k) {
            do {
                a[i++] = b[j++];
            } while (x != j);
            break ;
        }
    }
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    #endif
}


 int main(void) {
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    const int n = 100;
    int a[n];
    int b[n/2];
    int c[(n+1)/2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // initialize with random values
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;

    merge_sort(n, a, n/2, b, (n+1)/2, c);
}
```